# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS nginx with SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, digital-ocean, nginx-config, namecheap

After a lot of tries, I succeed to add proper SSL from namecheap,
that will secure my domain (with multiple ports).

I have some apps - that run on NGINX. My droplet is of Digital Ocean.

So I have a few blocks with this configuration:

```
#this is the default 80 port 
server {
#listen 80; # - will cause nginx complain on already in use. 
listen 443;

ssl on;

ssl_certificate /my/folder/forssl/my-domain_com_chain.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /home/projects/ssl-files/my-domain.com.key;

root /var/www/my-domain.com/so-ev;

server_name my-domain.com;

#all those tries didn't help
 #   return 301 https://so-ev-qa.shop$request_uri;
#return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
#rewrite ^(.*) https://so-ev-qa.shop$1 permanent;


}



server {

listen 26;

ssl on;

ssl_certificate /my/folder/forssl/my-domain_com_chain.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /home/projects/ssl-files/my-domain.com.key;

root /var/www/my-domain.com/html;

server_name my-domain.com;

}

server {

listen 3000 ;

ssl on;

ssl_certificate /my/folder/forssl/my-domain_com_chain.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /home/projects/ssl-files/my-domain.com.key;

root /var/www/my-domain.com/html2;

server_name my-domain.com;

}


server {
    listen 27;
     ssl on;

               
                ssl_certificate /my/folder/forssl/my-domain_com_chain.crt;

                ssl_certificate_key /home/projects/ssl-files/my-domain.com.key;

                server_name  my-domain.com;
                index index.html index.htm;
                access_log /var/log/nginx/bmiapp.log;
                error_log  /var/log/nginx/bmiapp-error.log error;

                location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:26;
                proxy_redirect off;
         }
}
```

Currently the problem is that it's not doing redirect from http to https.

While https://example.com is secured,
http://example.com isn't.

I am trying to do the simple redirecting action.

All my tries ended unsuccessfully.

If I'm trying to add block for listen 80, it's complain about [image: "already in use".]
All my other tries didn't work.

Help will be appreciated, I have spent on this SSL issues a lot of hours.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

There was an old-client service that was running on the background.

We can use

```
udo lsof -i:80
```

To get a clue